# d3.js Combo chart Line and Scatter

Tags: d3.js

I am very new to d3.js and i am trying to add a line on top of a scatter chart. I have two datasets to be drawn

```
var data = [ {
        "x" : 30,
        "y" : 30,
        "r" : 20,
        "c" : "green",
        "s" : "s1"
    }, {
        "x" : 70,
        "y" : 70,
        "r" : 20,
        "c" : "purple",
        "s" : "s2"
    }, {
        "x" : 110,
        "y" : 100,
        "r" : 20,
        "c" : "red",
        "s" : "s3"
    } ];

    var data1 = [{
        "x":30,
        "y":30},
        {"x":70,
            "y":70}];
```

The data variable is used as the scatter series and on the same chart i want to draw the second data set as a line series.

```
var margin = {
            top : 20,
            right : 20,
            bottom : 30,
            left : 40
        }, width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 500 - margin.top
                - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([ 0, width ]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("#"+div).append("svg").attr("width",
            width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",
            height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = [ {
        "x" : 30,
        "y" : 30,
        "r" : 20,
        "c" : "green",
        "s" : "s1"
    }, {
        "x" : 70,
        "y" : 70,
        "r" : 20,
        "c" : "purple",
        "s" : "s2"
    }, {
        "x" : 110,
        "y" : 100,
        "r" : 20,
        "c" : "red",
        "s" : "s3"
    } ];

    var data1 = [{
        "x":30,
        "y":30},
        {"x":70,
            "y":70}];

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {          
        return d.x;
    })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })).nice();

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform",
            "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).append("text").attr(
            "class", "label").attr("x", width).attr("y", -6).style(
            "text-anchor", "end").text("Yield");

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text")
            .attr("class", "label").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr(
                    "y", 6).attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Skew")

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
    svg.selectAll(".line").data(data1).enter().append("path").attr("class","line").attr("d",line);

    svg.selectAll(".dot").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("class",
            "dot").attr("r", 3.5).attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
    }).attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
    }).style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.c);
    });



    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").data(color.domain()).enter()
            .append("g").attr("class", "legend").attr("transform",
                    function(d, i) {
                        return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
                    });

    legend.append("rect").attr("x", width - 18).attr("width", 18).attr(
            "height", 18).style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text").attr("x", width - 24).attr("y", 9).attr("dy",
            ".35em").style("text-anchor", "end").text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

But i dont see the line drawn at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data([data1])  ( or datum(data1) ) and styling the line makes it appear:

```
svg.append("path")
        .data([data1])
    .attr("class","line")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d",line);
```

Before with:

```
svg.selectAll(".line").
        data(data1).enter()
    .append("path")
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("d",line);
```

a path element was being created for every point you wanted to plot.

```
<path class="line"></path>
<path class="line"></path>
```

and line was never getting called. Instead, we need one path object with the entire array of points bound to it. With that object, we add points with .attr("d", line) and end up with this:

```
<path class="line" stroke-width="1.5" d="M0,450L450,192.8571428571429"></path>
```

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures) by mbostock (and its links) for more on *why* this works.

Comment: Thanks, now i can see the line. Only problem is if i add one more data point to the data1 json array, it ends up with a polygon, the line is connected back to the first point in the array.

Comment: Yes. That did the trick. Though i thought it would just remove the fill and show me the polygon. Thanks.