# D3 - dealing with JSON nested data structures

Tags: d3.js

My post is somehow a follow-up to this question : [D3 - how to deal with JSON data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures)

In short, I'm in trouble with handling complex nested JSON structures. 
Let me give a simple sample (that mirrors the above link) to illustrate:

```
var regularData = [[40,20,30,24,18,40],
                    [24,20,30,41,12,34]];

var myTable = d3.select("body").append("table")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(regularData, function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("tr")
  .selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("td") 
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

As already shown through D3's doc, this produces two lines of numbers, as expected.

But if I replace regularData by this:

```
var newData = [{"user":"jim","scores":[40,20,30,24,18,40]},
            {"user":"ray","scores":[24,20,30,41,12,34]}];
```

and adapt the myTable's construction lines 3 to 5 with this:

```
  .data(newData, function(d) {
    return d.scores;
  })
```

I would have expected to loop in the scores for each user. Instead, the second data clause is still bound to top-level objects (i.e. with properties "user" and "scores").

A brute-force approach would be to cast my data in a plain "array of arrays" adapted to each purpose. But maybe I missed something, and a more elegant way is possible ?

Thanks by advance for your help,
P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have slightly misunderstood what the [second argument to `d3.data`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) is meant for.

That argument is used for [*object constancy*](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) by providing an *id* for the data and not as an accessor function, as in most other functions in the d3 API.

However, when a function is passed as the *first argument*, as is here:

```js
.data(function(d) {
  return d;
})
```

then it does behave as an accessor function.

In your case, what you want is something along these lines:

```js
var newData = [{"user":"jim","scores":[40,20,30,24,18,40]},
            {"user":"ray","scores":[24,20,30,41,12,34]}];

var myTable = d3.select("body").append("table")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(regularData, function(d) {
    return d.user;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("tr")
  .selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.scores;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("td") 
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

I have used the `user` field as the `id` of the data and have returned the `scores` in the second call to `data` to create the `td` elements.