# Using d3.selection.classed() with class value from datum

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am moving a number of items of styling from JS to CSS so I have better separation of concerns.

Now I would like to create my key by providing an array like

```
var keyItems = [
    {'forClass': 'tree', 'text':'Tree which has been maped'},
    {'forClass': 'pond', 'text':'Pond, not a puddle!'},
    {'forClass': 'contaminatedLand', 'text':'Do not go here'},
];
```

Yet as `d3.selection.classed()` takes a string and not a function I can't do

```
    .classed(function(d){return d.forclass;}
```

One can however do something like

```
keyItems.forEach(function(datum, index){
    keyEnter.selectAll('rect').classed(datum.forClass,function(d){
        return d.forClass == datum.forClass;
    })
})
```

But this feels like it is breaking the spirit of D3 and messy.

Feel free to take a look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z7Rv/)

---

**Question**

Is there a cleaner d3 like way to do this that I might have overlooked?

---

**Edit 1**

Made a little bit of progress in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L859x/) but any further improvements welcome.

```
.each(function(d){
        d3.select(this).classed(d.forClass, true)
})
```

Comment: `.attr('class',function(d){return d.forClass;});`

Answer (score 1):

```
keyEnter
  .append('rect')
    .attr('height', 5)
    .attr('width', 5)
    .attr('x', 20)
    .attr('y', function(d, i){return (i+0.25) * 30;})
    .attr('class',function(d){return d.forClass;});
```

do same for text...

Comment: Knew I was missing something obvious. (I have a feeling that class use to not behave nice when you did something like `.attr('class', 'a').attr('class','b')` but I have just checked and that works fine now)

Comment: @ChristopherHackett Yes, it works well for this case while the `.classed...` approach works great for toggling.

Comment: Cam some one say me why datum is instead in function? And whats the meaning of datum?

Comment: From the docs: "Gets or sets the bound data for each selected element. Unlike the selection.data method, this method does not compute a join (and thus does not compute enter and exit selections)." More [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728402/what-is-the-difference-d3-datum-vs-data)...follow the links and you will get to an [explanation from Mike Bostock himself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures). Hope this helps.