# I get an error on my .enter() d3

Tags: d3.js

im trying to make a graph. im using d3 to .enter() to insert the data. i get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the .enter() . The datum definitely put data in #act.

```
d3.select("#act")
    .datum(Avg(actD))
.enter().append("div")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.enter()` with `.datum()`, since you are not performing a `join`:

```
d3.select("#act")
    .datum(Avg(actD))
    .append("div")
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures) from Mike Bostock or [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum) for reference.

Comment: I don't believe that code will work without using `selectAll("div")` first.

Comment: see this codepen http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/mhDLg. You have to select the empty set first before you do operations on it, right? Also , wouldnt `.datum(Avg(actD))` need to be `.datum([Avg(actD)])` as per the OP's comment above.

Comment: @agconti: not sure I understand, check out [this counterexample](http://codepen.io/mdml/pen/jmqgx). With `.datum`, you don't need to wrap the datum in an `array`. You just need a selection to operate on, and *cannot use `.enter()`*.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to take out `.enter()` from my own counter example.  +1 for a solution that works and for referencing mike bostock.

Comment: @agconti: glad it works for you too, I thought I was losing my mind =)

Answer (score 0):

Use the D3 method `data`:

```
d3.select("#act")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(Avg(actD))
    .enter().append("div")
```

`data` works for single and multiple data points. If you use datum it does not compute a join so you cannot use `.enter()` method to append a div.

From the docs:

> selection.datum([value])
>
> Gets or sets the bound data for each selected element. Unlike the
>   selection.data method, this method does not compute a join (and thus
>   does not compute enter and exit selections).

---

Example;

```
d3.select("#act")
  .selectAll("div") // you need to first select an the existing / empty set before you append.
  .data([0]).enter()
  .append("div")
  .html("appended")
  .style("background-color", "red");
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/HtnJz

Comment: for some reason when i put in .data i dont add anything. if i type into my console:    d3.select("#act").data() i get [undefined]

Comment: @user3813223 I'll put an example up.

Comment: thanks i just needed the brackets around my variable .data([Avg(actD)])

Comment: @user3813223 no problem. If my post answered your question can you please accept it by clicking on the check to the right?