# D3 data() vs. datum()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In Mike Bostock’s ‘[Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)’ why the initial data link to `<p>`  element is made with datum(data):

```
d3.csv("sp500.csv", function(data) {
  var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y");

  d3.select("#example")
      .datum(data)
    .call(timeSeriesChart()
      .x(function(d) { return formatDate.parse(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return +d.price; }));
});
```

while further link of data to `<svg>` element inside the chart() function is made with data([data]):

```
// Select the svg element, if it exists.
var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

// Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "area");
gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "line");
gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
```

In his own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures) Mike says that these two approaches are interchangeable, except the former doesn’t compute a join. So why to use data([data]) here?

Also I don’t quite get what happens if there is already an `<svg>` element as the comment line suggests. For me the enter selection is empty in this case and no further append will work…

I must be misunderstanding something…

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using `.data([data])` in the second case is that if there's no SVG, the handling of the enter selection adds it. If the SVG exists, the code is exactly equivalent to `.datum(data)` -- the data bound to the element is changed and nothing else happens.