# Make barchart with one object of data

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to make a barchart with on-click data from a worldmap. When the users clicks on a country, the chart returns certain data with which I want to make a bar chart (for this particular question i only want 1 bar). The data[index], which i want to visualise in my barchart, in this particular example looks like this when i console.log() it:

```
Object {CountryName: "United States", CountryCode: "USA", GDP: 17419000000000, Variable: 24}
```

I already fixed the X-axis and the Y-axis, but until now it still makes all the bars from the other countries, which are in the original data. Could anyone explain to me how i can make a single bar in my barchart from the object above?

For drawing the bars i've got the following code:

```
// draw the bars
        svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return (d.CountryName); })
            .attr ({
                "x": function(d) {return xScale(d.CountryCode);},
                "y": function(d) {return yScale(d.Variable);},
                "width": xScale.rangeBand(),
                "height": function(d) { return height - yScale(d.Variable);}
            })
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

It feels like i tried everything to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: dont use `data(data)`. Use the same subset that you just put in `console.log`.

Comment: I tried that as well. But then nothing is shown in the barchart, not even any errors in the console.

Comment: It ended up that I had to use datatemp = [data[index]] and then do .data(datatemp)

Comment: Sorry, mate! I should have told you, it has to be inside an array... I thought you knew it. Check this answer from Bostock: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures

Comment: @StijnRobben post your solution as an answer pls :)

Answer (score 0):

I only had to push the object into an array and draw the bars from this array.

```
var datatemp = [];

datatemp.push(data)

// draw the bars
        svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(datatemp)
        .enter()    
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("id", function(d) {return d.CountryName })
            .attr ({
                "x": function(d) {return xScale(d.CountryName);},
                "y": function(d) {return yScale(d.Variable);},
                "width": xScale.rangeBand(),
                "height": function(d) { return height - yScale(d.Variable);}
            })
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```